# Google Colab Custom GCE VM Connection: The requested VM does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, google-compute-engine

Every time i try to connect to my GCE VM from google colab it says the VM doesnt exist. I cant seem to find a fix to this issue anywhere. I am using the Colab Marketplace VM image.

I tried stopping and starting the VM a couple times and making it in different regions but it never worked.